# Multiplication 2 $_POST Arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, post

I want to multiply 2 `$_POST` array values with each other and `echo` the sum on submit.

In this case it should be `$_POST['vindue1']` and `$_POST['quantity']`

I have tried:

```
echo "<p><strong>Your price:  </strong>" . $_POST['vindue1'] * $_POST['quantity']. " Kr. </p>";
```

CODE:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<div class="dropdown-option">
    <select id="select" name="vindue1">
        <option value="" >VÆLG POLERINGSTYPE</option>
        <option value="60" <?php if(isset($_POST['vindue1']) &&  $_POST['vindue1'] == '60'){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>INDVENDIG + UDVENDIG</option>
        <option value="40" <?php if(isset($_POST['vindue1']) &&  $_POST['vindue1'] == '40'){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>UDVENDIG</option>
        <option value="40" <?php if(isset($_POST['vindue1']) &&  $_POST['vindue1'] == '40'){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>INDVENDIG</option>
        <option value="85" <?php if(isset($_POST['vindue1']) &&  $_POST['vindue1'] == '85'){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>FORSATS (INKL. INDVENDIG + UDVENDIG)</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="quantity-field">
    <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="100" placeholder="STK.">
</div>

<div class="dropdown-option">
    <select id="select" name="vindue2">
        <option value="" selected>VÆLG POLERINGSTYPE</option>
        <option value="90" <?php if(isset($_POST['vindue2']) &&  $_POST['vindue2'] == '60'){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>INDVENDIG + UDVENDIG</option>
        <option value="65" <?php if(isset($_POST['vindue2']) &&  $_POST['vindue2'] == '60'){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>UDVENDIG</option>
        <option value="65" <?php if(isset($_POST['vindue2']) &&  $_POST['vindue2'] == '60'){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>INDVENDIG</option>
        <option value="125" <?php if(isset($_POST['vindue2']) &&  $_POST['vindue2'] == '60'){ echo 'selected'; } else { echo ''; } ?>>FORSATS (INKL. INDVENDIG + UDVENDIG)</option>
    </select>

<div class="quantity-field">
        <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="100" placeholder="STK.">
 </div>

<div class="row contact-form-pris">                     
    <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
        <label for="first_name">Fornavn *</label>
        <input class="" name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
        <label for="last_name">Efternavn *</label>
        <input class="" name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <label for="address_street">Adresse *</label>
        <input class="" name="address_street" id="address_street" type="text" required/>    
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
        <label for="email_address">Email *</label>
        <input class="" name="email_address" id="email_address" type="email" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
        <label for="mobile_no">Telefon *</label>
        <input class="" name="mobile_no" id="mobile_no" type="tel" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="large-12 columns text-center">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="MODTAG UFORPLIGTENDE TILBUD" class="submit-pris">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just changed it to "quantity". 

Okay, I'm pretty new at PHP, so I thought it was post arrays

Comment: Is de given HTML code wrapped inside a form with post method? Is the echo statement always outputted or just after post? When it is always outputted, then it could be due the fact that on request, the post variable isnt populated

Comment: Are you getting $_POST data correctly ? Can you verify it?

Comment: Is that HTML code wrapped in  `<form>...</form>` tags?? If so SHOW THEM, if not it needs to be

Comment: I can for instance multiplay vindue1 * vindue2 and it's echo the sum. 
and the form use post method, sorry not for posting that.

Comment: Your code works correctly for me but only as long as the form method is `POST`. If it is `GET` it doesn't work (as one would expect).

Comment: So you can multiply $vindue1 and $quantity and get the sum?

Comment: There could be 100 reasons for your issue, all of which are in code **you are not showing us** Are you doing any checking that these values actually exist? Are you sure you are not forgetting to select a dropdown that has a valid value??

Comment: Obviously, if you select the first option in your select list then it will always show `0 kr` because your first option has no `value` set.

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig yes, I can do that. The only change I made to your code is that I added the form tags with the post method and put your first code snippet in there too. It's like RiggsFolly says, though, there may be other problems in the unseen code...

Comment: Not reproducible with PHP 5.6.

Comment: So if I delete the value="" it could work?

Comment: Well ONLY if that is the option you have selected in the dropdown. Select a line in the dropdown that contains a VALID value. Does you calc work then? Or is this an issue that happens only on the first execution of this script i.e. BEFORE user has the chance to select ANYTHING

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, thanks a lot you all!

Comment: Oh dear dog where has my will to live gone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add bracket and use `intval()` function
Like this: `echo "<p><strong>Your price:  </strong>" . (intval($_POST['vindue1']) * intval($_POST['quantity'])). " Kr. </p>";`

Comment: Cool, I will try that :) 
Thanks